# JavaScript read file contents

Tags: javascript

how can you retrieve the data from a document with javascript that isn't the page you are on if you have the url of the new document.
what i am trying to do is create a page that has a text field for providing a local file name and a button that retrieves the words from the document provided.

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

HTML5 has a File API that lets you read local files. It's supported in at least Firefox (3.6 and later, I think) and Chrome. I don't know if any other browsers support it yet or not. If you need to support other browsers, you'll have to fall back to something like Flash, but I don't have any experience with that.

Unfortunately, by default Chrome doesn't allow local files to access other local files (each file is considered to be from its own domain). You can explicitly allow it by adding the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag when you launch Chrome.

Here's a good introduction to the File API with several examples: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/.

Answer (score 1):

Browser security does not allow direct access to the local filesystem. If it could, web pages would be able to steal any file of your machine.

[HTML5 local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) does allow local access, but on a different principle.

Comment: the whole thing is local so i keep the file i want to read in the same place where i have the main page.

Comment: and i can open it if i provide the url, i just don't know how to get around retrieving the data

Comment: Newer browsers can read local files using the HTML5 "File API", but not if the page itself is a local file (at least by default).

Comment: If it's a local file, out your data in a JavaScript file in JSON format. You can read that.