# PGP encryption from client side (js) with JSF 2

Tags: jsf-2, pgp

when client select a file with upload component, I need to implement PGP encryption from client side with JSF 2 (Create a faces component) or primefaces 2.2 (I dont see anything from client side in  the upload component), because the file has confidential information, encryption from the server does not help, can you give me some help or any idea?

Answer (score 0):

JSF/PrimeFaces wont help you much - if you have to encrypt the file before sending it will all have to be done client side in JavaScript. So you have to read the file in JS, encrypt in JS, and then you can encode encrypted contents with something like Base64, assign that value to inputText and then submit to server.

See [JavaScript read file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265091/javascript-read-file-contents)
and
http://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/

Comment: ok, the encryption must be PGP , I said JSF/Primefaces because if I applied Javascript must be in the Upload Component, and this uses AJAX request when the client submit the file, I use the tag <p:fileUpload> of Primefaces 2.2, no matter if I will use <input type="file">, but in the jsf Bean must be arrives te data

Comment: sorry, when I Submit the form is With AJAX <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="true"> not the component. I apologize

Comment: input type=file will always upload local file without any encryption. If you insist on using standard HTML file upload mechanism you will have to encode the file and place it on disk, then you can upload it. My answer involved reading the file, encoding it in JS, then uploading as base64-encoded text instead of file. This way you can provide more streamlined user experience